# Laravel: полностью удалить миграцию

Tags: laravel

На вопрос "как удалить миграцию в Laravel" все обычно приводят решение вроде `php artisan migrate:refresh`. Но ведь никакого удаления миграции не произойдёт: действия, описанные в миграции, которую я хочу удалить, всё равно будут выполнены. Меня же интересует то, чтобы действия, описанные в миграции, повторно не выполнялись и вообще файл с ненужной миграцией больше не мешался.

Comment: Вроде как database/migration удалить файл описания миграции. Разве нет?

Comment: @Vasily Koshelev, прошу прощения, не понял, что Вы хотели спросить. Что такое database/migration? Путь? Команда? Далее грамматику не понял.

Comment: Путь от корня проекта на Laravel

Comment: @Vasily Koshelev, файл-то удалить можно, но запись миграции останется. Не очень страшно, просто консоль будет задалбливать сообщением `Migration not found:`. При технически правильных способах ничего такого быть не должно.

Comment: Если миграция тебе больше вообще не нужна, откатись при помощи migration:rollback за нее, т.е. так, что б выполнился метод down этой миграции (там должна быть операция обратная up если создание было таблицы то удаление, если создание столбца то удаление его ) при этом из базы и таблицы migration удалится запись о миграции и больше никаких ошибок у тебя не будет , ну а потом можешь удалить файл с миграцией этой и запустить php artisan migrate